# QSortFilterProxyModel - get the number of filtered items

Tags: python, qt, qsortfilterproxymodel

If you do so

```
    def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, source_parent):
    # Assign a role for filtering
    if self.findCheckType == True:
        self.setFilterRole(Devices.DevicetypeRole)
    elif self.findCheckDepart == True:
        self.setFilterRole(Devices.DepartmentRole)
    self.countFindItems = self.rowCount()
    return super(SelectModel, self).filterAcceptsRow(source_row, source_parent)
```

The compiler throws an error

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 193.5662.61)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\.....\app.py", line 1230, in filterAcceptsRow
self.countFindItems = self.rowCount()
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

How can I get the number of filtered items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you modify filter inside `filterAcceptsRow` it invalidates filter which causes `filterAcceptsRow` evaluated for all rows, which is infinite loop.

Number of filtered rows can be calculated like this: `self.sourceModel().rowCount() - self.rowCount()`.

Also instead of `if something == True:` you can write `if something:`.